# Add jQuery to the MEAN project

Tags: jquery, angular, modal-dialog, mean

How can I add jQuery to the MEAN project, that I could use modal windows, tabs, sliders? I added some components to angular, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use jQuery in your project by including jQuery cdn in index.html at the bottom before closing body tag or you can Install jquery with npm